# Map NDVI from MODIS image for a specific country

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, ndvi, modis-reprojection-tool

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB/2013')
            .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(-7.681, 53.43));
var image = ee.Image().float().paint(dataset, 'iso_num');

var visParams = {
 palette: ['f5ff64', 'b5ffb4', 'beeaff', 'ffc0e8', '8e8dff', 'adadad'],
 min: 0.0,
 max: 894.0,
 opacity: 0.8,
 };
 Map.addLayer(image, visParams, 'USDOS/LSIB/2013');

 // The input image has a SR-ORG:6974 (sinusoidal) projection.
 var image1 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD13A1')
           .filter(ee.Filter.date('2016-01-01', '2016-01-31'))
           .filterBounds(dataset)
           .mean();

var ndvi = image1.select('NDVI');
var ndviVis = {
 palette: [
'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
'66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
'012E01', '011D01', '011301'
 ],
 };
 Map.addLayer(ndvi, ndviVis, 'NDVI');
```

This is my code, it works, however, the map shows the NDVI for the entire world. Is it because of the different coordination system? I tried to convert it to the same, but the Google Earth Engine API only had the projection transformation of a single image, and do not have the code for transformation of the image collection. How can I do it?

This is the link of my code https://code.earthengine.google.com/c1132b4753acf26b4ce5f93cca6ff070

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clip your image to the geometry you're interested in:

```
var ndvi = image1.select('NDVI').clip(dataset.geometry());
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0f3776e9e41fd209f55eda4f3a8e84ad

Comment: Hi, Thank you and it works. so do you know what's the matter with my code? Why use clip(dataset.geometry() instead of using clip.(dataset). Because it(clip.(dataset)) works in the Landsat and Sentinel data for mapping NDVI